# Error when subtotal (ITEMAMT) is $0.00

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

When I try to use the PayPal API with a subtotal of $0.00, I receive the error:

> [10413] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

Here's the request data being passed to SetExpressCheckout (with personal info replaced with ...):

```
    [0] => L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=9.99
    [1] => L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Name
    [2] => L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
    [3] => L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=1
    [4] => L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=-9.99
    [5] => L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Discount
    [6] => L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1
    [7] => L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=0
    [8] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=2.51
    [9] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=0.00
    [10] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=2.38
    [11] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.13
    [12] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=...
    [13] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=...
    [14] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=...
    [15] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=...
    [16] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=...
    [17] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=...
    [18] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=...
    [19] => PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=...
    [20] => CANCELURL=...
    [21] => RETURNURL=...
    [22] => NOSHIPPING=1
    [23] => ALLOWNOTE=0
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=0.00' must be greater than zero.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf
page 72

[....Character length and limitations: Value is a positive number which cannot exceed $10,000 USD in any currency.....]

Comment: I think that's for AMT, not ITEMAMT (which is the sum of all of the AMTs).

Comment: If ITEMAMT is the sum of all AMTs, and every AMT has to be greater than zero, then the ITEMAMT cannot be zero by definition.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you’re trying to accomplish here. Do you want to “sell” an item for free but still be able to charge for shipping and taxes? In your example, AMT ist the sum of ITEMAMT, SHIPPINGAMT and TAXAMT and not (as you state in your comment) “ITEMAMT […] is the sum of all of the AMTs”…

Comment: @Matthias - AMT's don't have to be greater than zero. The way discounts are passed to PayPal is by passing a negative AMT (which you can see I did in my question). The PayPal documentation shows discounts working this way.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert - Sometimes I give customers coupon that result in the cart subtotal being $0.00, but they still need to complete checkout (for multiple reasons, one being that I want a record of the order in PayPal, another being that shipping is still charged and they need to pay for that).

Comment: I do think this answer is sound: the linked documentation is relatively clear that neither `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMAMT` nor `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMTm` nor `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT` can be negative or even zero. Where did you get that example with the discount?

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert - Passing a discount though an item with a negative price is the correct way to pass a discount to PayPal -- it's in the documentation somewhere and it works fine, the only issue is when the item subtotal is $0.00. The answer isn't "sound," it's completely wrong.

Comment: @Nate so you’re basically using the documentation to argue against the documentation. At least zack’s answer provides a source whereas you still haven’t provided one for the negative discount example. Maybe this answer is not a solution but how about the following for a solution: why not take $0.01 from the shipping costs and add them to the discount (thus reducing it by $0.01).

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't see order total parameter in your code. Please check it!

Meanwhile I tested call with following parameters:

```
            List<PaymentDetailsItemType> lineItems = 
                              new ArrayList<PaymentDetailsItemType>();

            PaymentDetailsItemType item = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
            BasicAmountType amt = new BasicAmountType();

            amt.setCurrencyID(CurrencyCodeType.fromValue(dto.getCurrencyCode()));
            amt.setValue("9.99");

            item.setAmount(amt);

            item.setQuantity(dto.getItemQuantity());
            item.setName("Name");
            item.setNumber("1");

            lineItems.add(item);

            PaymentDetailsItemType item1 = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
            BasicAmountType amt1 = new BasicAmountType();

            amt1.setCurrencyID(CurrencyCodeType.fromValue(dto.getCurrencyCode()));
            amt1.setValue("-9.99");

            item1.setAmount(amt1);
            item1.setQuantity(dto.getItemQuantity());
            item1.setName("Discount");
            item1.setNumber("0");
            lineItems.add(item1);
            ...

        BasicAmountType itemsTotal = new BasicAmountType();
        itemsTotal.setValue(Double.toString(itemTotal));

        BasicAmountType orderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
        orderTotal.setValue(Double.toString(orderTotal));
```

The `itemTotal` and `orderTotal` are 0. I got `10525: This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero.`

Perhaps my code works with another parameters, then your code. I think if you add order total to your code, you will get same 10525.

Please check it!

**EDIT:**

I found this explenation in net:

> If one or more of the subtotals is zero, you can either include the
>   field in the request with a value of zero, pass an empty string, or
>   leave the field out of the request altogether. However, the sum of the
>   remaining subtotal fields, if any are specified, must add up to AMT.

[Here is a link.](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/expresscheckout.html)

Comment: Yes, I get that error if the order total is zero, but in my case the order total isn't zero, it's the subtotal that's zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an item temporary for check out and add more Discount Shipping to subtract amount of item temporary. Paypal accept minimum amount is $0.01.
Here id my code. It work for my case:

```
            var itemDetails = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
            itemDetails.Name = "Shipping and Handling";
            itemDetails.Amount = new BasicAmountType(currency, "0.01");
            itemDetails.Quantity = 1;
            //itemDetails.Tax = new BasicAmountType(currency, tax.ToString());
            itemDetails.ItemCategory = ItemCategoryType.PHYSICAL;


            itemDetails.Description = "Item temporary for payment.";
            paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem.Add(itemDetails);

            itemTotal = (double)0.01;
            paymentDetails.ShippingDiscount = new BasicAmountType(currency, "-0.01");
```